# Laravel 7 on VDS (virtual dedicated server), Centos 7

Tags: centos, centos-7, vdsl

I need to install and run **Laravel 7 on VDS** (virtual dedicated server), Centos 7.
I've followed this instruction: https://tecadmin.net/install-laravel-framework-on-centos/ yet **example.laravel.com** does not work...

> This site can’t be reached example.laravel.com’s server IP address
> could not be found. Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Answer (score 0):

`example.laravel.com` is just an example host (which you do not own, and cannot manage it's DNS Records)..

you need to replace this example host with your OWN hostname, which points to YOUR VDS's IP